# Regular expression, get the rest of the text aswell

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file, a regular expression that looks in that file and gets the things I want. I also write this new information into a new file, however not everything is written to the new file! The file that my regex reads from looks like this:

> "This is my text, it contains of 53 or so words file. That is a very
>   good number. However 80 is a better number. Hopefully I can write more
>   words soon enough. Hopefully very very soon "

What is written to the new text file is:

> "This is my text, it contains of 53 or so words file. That is a very
>   good number. However 80 is a better number. Hopefully I can write more
>   words"

I want everything to be written. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the regex u used?

Comment: [\d.]+ is what I used

Comment: What are "the things I want" what are you looking for in the text? If your just rewriting everything you don't need regex

Comment: There is no code here; therefore, it is not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without the regex you were using, it's impossible to say.

I would hazard a guess though, that what you need to do is stick `.*$` on the end of the capture group, in order to grab the rest of the text on the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\s\S]*$
```

should do it for you.